# problem with serving static files of django on server with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, server

Hi everyone I have changed default file of nginx where is in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default as below

```
upstream django {
server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
listen 80;

location /static/ {
root /home/django/chistaa/chistaa/settings;
try_files $uri =404;
}

location / {
try_files $uri @send_to_django;
}

location @send_to_django {
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://django;
}
}
```

but it doesnt load my static files. 
What did I wrong?!

Comment: With this settings requested file `/static/style.css` will be searched in `/home/django/chistaa/chistaa/settings/static` directory. Is this correct?

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: I thought you expecting that it will be searched `/home/django/chistaa/chistaa/settings` directory instead. If I was wrong everything other looks ok with your config. Do you have SELinux enabled on your server?

Comment: I don't know what is SELinux

Comment: What is the output of `sudo sestatus` command?

Comment: sudo: unable to resolve host axms
sudo: sestatus: command not found

Comment: So this isn't a SELinux problem either. Can you show an nginx error log entry for a static file request?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know where are your nginx error log located? Request a static file in the browser and get an error, error log file will be appended with new line, copy this line and post it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215531/discussion-between-sam-and-ivan-shatsky).